# Run a script in Google Sheets from an html web application

Tags: javascript, html, urlfetch

I’m trying to run a script remotely as per the instructions at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute. The script shares the same GCP project with the web application and has already been implemented as an executable API. The GCP project already has the necessary credentials to run, but I can't run the script remotely:

API executable (URL): https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/AKf...JYC:run

OAuth 2.0 Client IDs: {"web":{"client_id":"903...h7l.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"upl...615","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"ZPg...aHJ","redirect_uris":["https://www.prooptica.pe/activador.html"],"javascript_origins":["https://www.prooptica.pe"]}}

Here is my code:

```
<div class="group group-xl offset-top-20 offset-sm-top-50">
  <button
    id="button"
    class="btn btn-icon btn-icon-left btn-primary btn-lg btn-anis-effect"
    data-caption-animate="fadeInUp"
    data-caption-delay="1200"
  >
    My Button
  </button>
</div>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    const options = {
      headers: {
        web: {
          client_id: "903...h7l.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          project_id: "upl...615",
          auth_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
          token_uri: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
          auth_provider_x509_cert_url:
            "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
          client_secret: "ZPg...aHJ",
          redirect_uris: ["https://www.myweb.com/button.html"],
          javascript_origins: ["https://www.myweb.com"],
        },
      },
      method: "post",
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/AKf...JYC:run",
      options
    );
  }
  document.getElementById("button").onclick = myFunction;
</script>
```

Maybe someone can give me a little light on this...